# Add a licence key to SQL Server 2008 after it has been installed

Tags: sql-server, licensing

I have a machine that has had SQL Server 2008 installed on it, but I forgot to enter the licence key while installing.

It's now complaining that I have fifty days before it locks down, because I still haven't entered the licence key.

The trouble is, I can't figure out *where* to enter the key.  Is there a menu option somewhere or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start the SQL Server Setup select Maintenance => Edition Upgrade. This should allow you to enter the License Key.